# Expressing wish using past perfect and simple past

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

What's the difference between these two sentences? One uses past perfect, the other uses simple past. Which is more appropriate for wishing that something really happened in the past?

> I wish I **had** studied English.
>
> I wish I studied English.

Am I required to specify an event when using the past perfect? E.g.

> I wish I **had** studied English **before I came to the United States.**

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @WS2 is good as far as it goes.

But "I wish I studied English" does work.  Consider

> I wish I worked at IBM.

This means *I wish I were employed at IBM.*

So with the English study, the sentence without the "had" means *I wish I were enrolled in an English class* or *I wish I had an English teacher to work with*.  (Self-study would also be an option, of course.)

Granted, "I wish I had studied" (in the past) is more commonly encountered.

Comment: *I wish I studies English* could mean past or present - more likely present.

Answer (score 0):

The past perfect is the one you need. Strictly an event is required, unless it is obvious to your addressee, or they were aware you were speaking very generally.

**Edit**.
After considering comments made I would agree that no "event" need be expressed. But the past perfect is the only way of indicating that you are not talking about the present moment - which the simple past would imply.

Comment: The past perfect is the one you need but the event isn't necessary.

In your example "I wish I had studied English before I came to the United States…" In the broad context the extra clause makes the sentence more interesting; perhaps even more useful but grammatically, it makes no more difference than "I wish I had studied English when I was wearing green socks…"

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin You are correct, see my further edit. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks WS2 and you're still right about the past perfect